# Issues with audio playback during network activity

Tags: ios, multithreading, asihttprequest, core-audio, spotify

I'm using CocoaLibSpotify and the `SPPlaybackManager` to stream Spotify music to my app. It works very well overall, but I'm experiencing some issues with the playback during other network activity.

**Procedure:**

1. (During audio playback) I'm firing a regular `ASIHTTPRequest` to a server.
2. When the request has finished, I'm making a number of Spotify searches using `SPSearch`.
3. On many devices (in particular iPhone 3GS), I'm getting massive "stuttering"/"skips"/"pauses" in the playback while the Searches are performed.

*Earlier, I used regular `ASIHTTPRequests` instead of the `SPSearch` class, so I'm quite sure it's got to do with the overall network activity.*

Also, the playback issues may appear while doing some other network activity on the device, i.e. loading a number of emails in the Mail app.

**Threading?**

I'm guessing this is some kind of threading issue (i.e. the audio is played back on the main thread or something), but I'm not sure exactly how to approach the issue... I've tried invoking `SPPlaybackManager#playTrack::` on a background thread, but I guess the setup wasn't 100% correct (since the issues remained).

Does anyone have any pointers as to how I should move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the audio delivery and audio playback in the classes supplied with CocoaLibSpotify are run on (different) background threads. However, `SPPlaybackManager` is only intended to be an easy-to-follow example of dealing with audio playback using Core Audio - it hasn't been tested for, nor is it intended for, use during high CPU load and/or in environments very tight on resources.

All I can do is point you towards the standard debugging tools such as Instruments to trace and profile what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. After doing some more profiling, one of the issues seems to be that I tried running many `SPSearch`:es in parallel. Changing it to a sequence at least made it less CPU intensive. Still seeing some issues with CPU spikes during network traffic, though.

You knowing a lot about coding audio streams, can you give any tips as to handle such a situation? Is there a way to make audio stream work "better" even under high CPU usage?

Comment: To be more specific: On a 3GS, it's up on 100% total load (according to the Activity Monitor) when shooting requests during playback.

Comment: If you're at 100% load, you need to reduce something in order for the audio threads to keep up with the realtime needs. Reducing the amount of code in the Core Audio render callback can help if you can do it, as might increasing the buffer size.

Comment: What are the possible side-effects from changing the buffer size? And are there any recommendations as to how much I should increase it? From what I can tell, it's set to "44100 * 2 * 2 * 0.5" in the `SPPlaybackManager` included in libspotify?

Comment: That's 44100kHz * 2 channels * 2 bytes per sample * 0.5 seconds. Change the 0.5 bit to the number of seconds you want the buffer to last.

Comment: Increasing the buffer didn't help, I'm afraid. Will try to see if I can tweak the playback code some more.